# Did the Hork-Bajir relocate after the Yeerks invaded their valley?

Tags: animorphs

In #47 The Resistance, the Yeerks discover where the valley of the free Hork-Bajir is, and subsequently invade it. The Yeerks are eventually forced to retreat.

In the following books, the Animorphs, their families and the free Hork-Bajir continue to live in something they refer to as  "the valley" or "the valley of the free Hork-Bajir".

1. Is this the same valley that the Hork-Bajir used to live in before the Yeerk attack? (The one hidden by the Ellimist.)

Wouldn't the Yeerks have returned to that Valley with reinforcements to wipe out the free Hork-Bajir?

2. So if yes to #1, how could it be safe for everybody to live there when the Yeerks knew of its location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's not the same valley

In the final chapter of book 47: The Resistance, the Hork-Bajir and the Animorphs leave the valley the Hork-Bajir were living in, until the end of the war (at which time they presumably return).

> Toby had a diagonal slash across her chest and blood dripping from her fingers, but she was seeing to her people.
>
> Comforting, commending.
>
> Explaining that it was time to leave the valley.
>
> At least for a while.
>
> ...
>
> Everyone mourned the dead, but the colony knew it had to move out quickly.
>
> Now that the trees had burned, Visser One might be back with Bug Fighters. He might be mad enough to risk detection.
>
> It would be a long and painful march up and out of the valley and into the hills.
>
> I pulled Toby away from her preparations.
>
> "You know they'll be back. Not today, but soon."
>
> She nodded.
>
> "I know, Jake. But we won today. It may not feel like victory, but the valley is ours now. Forever. We've paid for it."
>
> She took a deep breath.
>
> "We'll stay away until the war is over. We know we have to. We had our chance to fight for freedom. That's all we really wanted."

Comment: Side note: it's really annoying trying to quote something when it's usually one sentence per paragraph.

Comment: Shhhhh... You're reminding me that I'm reading children's books at the age of 27.